# Chi-Squared p-value calculation without using a chart [algorithm]

Tags: javascript, algorithm, floating-point, statistics, p-value

I'm trying to implement a [Chi-Square test in combination with Marascuilo's procedure](http://www.prenhall.com/behindthebook/0136149901/pdf/Levine_CH12.pdf) in JavaScript.

The hardest part about this is calculating the p-value for the Chi-Squared test. There are many calculators out there but I don't want to just plug in numbers, I want to know the math behind them.

This [calculation in C](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/432194/How-to-Calculate-the-Chi-Squared-P-Value) looks like exactly what I'm looking for (besides needing to translate it to javascript), but the magic numbers make it hard to follow what is being computed.

On a higher level, what is the algorithm for calculating Chi-Squared p-value without using a chart?

Comment: The formula for chi-squared p-values is one minus the chi-squared cdf, that is, 1 - gamma(k/2, x/2)/Gamma(k/2), where k is the degrees of freedom, x is the chi-squared value, gamma is the incomplete gamma function, and Gamma is the (complete) gamma function. Why the cdf is what it is is a question for another site. The people who understand the tricks involved in computing the gamma functions probably are following the [tag:floating-point] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code from

> https://www.swogstat.org/stat/public/chisq_calculator.htm

could give you a hint